# Discord.js fetching 5 particular messages with a 404 fails completely

Tags: javascript, promise, frameworks, discord.js

I only want to fetch these particular messages not everything in between that's why I'm not using

`fetch({limit: 10})`

starting point is :

```
const discord = require('discord.js'); //@12.2.0
const bot = new discord.Client();
const config = require('./../../config.json');


messagesToCache = [
    "720062178790473769",
    "720062188991283296",
    "720062198323347486",   //missing message
    "720062209824391278"
]

let promises = [];

const logit = () =>{
    console.log(promises)
}

bot.once('ready', async ()=>{
        console.log("ready");
        channel = await bot.channels.fetch("712405355740790835")
        let i = 0;
        for(const id of messagesToCache){
            console.log("fetching ", id)
            promises.push(channel.messages.fetch(id).then((msg)=>{
                console.log(msg.content);
                logit();
                i++;
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.error(err);
                logit();
                i++;
            }))
        }

})

bot.login(config.token);
```

but event tho the 404 is handled it prevents the 4th promise which is already pending from resolving. any advice ?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i`? you're not using it

Comment: What you have is effectively `let promises = messagesToCache.map(id => channel.messages.fetch(id));`
Hard to see why any fetch failure should affect any of the others.

Comment: If you were to aggregate the promises with `Promise.all()` then any single (uncaught) failure would cause the aggregated promise to fail, but that's not what you are doing.

Comment: @Syntle sry i stripped the code to make it more focused on the problem i use `i` i just forgot about it.

@Roamer-1888 hence the question here. the bigger problem is why are other promises not resolving even if the are already pending is that a thing ?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 in the original i used  `forEach()` does that provide more insight ?

Comment: @seeyouinthefuture, in this case `forEach(...)` and `for() {...}` amount to the same thing. It would be different if there was an `await` in the loop.